# Unable to parse span tag using python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am unable to parse the date in the form of " 2022-11-26 "
Used css selector and xpath but could parse the "2022-" in the span tag
Can you please advise me on the same?

```
<div class="medium-widget event-widget last">
 <div class="shrubbery">
  <h2 class="widget-title"><span aria-hidden="true" class="icon-calendar"></span>Upcoming Events</h2>
   <p class="give-me-more"><a href="/events/calendars/" title="More Events">More</a></p>
    <ul class="menu">
     <li>
      <time datetime="2022-11-26T00:00:00+00:00"><span class="say-no-more">2022-</span>11-26</time>
        <a href="/events/python-events/1331/">De Ja vu</a></li>
      <li>
    <ul>
```

I tried to get the year string only but did not get any output

year = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".event-widget time span")

Comment: `11-26` is not part of the `<span>` tag, it is part of the `<time>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//time").text
```

It gives the output as:

```
2022-11-26
```

Comment: I tried the same but it is giving me only "11-26" as an output and not the whole time.

Comment: From html source you've posted, I tried this, and got the above output.